# Linux count files with a specific string at a specific position in filename

Tags: linux, string, filenames

I have a directory which contains data for several years and several months.
Filenames have the format yy/mm/dd, f.e.

20150415,
20170831,
20121205

How can I find all data with month = 3?
F.e.

20150302,
20160331,
20190315

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -ltra ????03??
```

A question mark is a wildcard which stands for one character, so as your format seems to be `YYYYmmDD`, the regular expression `????03??` should stand for all files having `03` as `mm`.

**Edit**
Apparently the files have format `YYYYmmDDxxx`, where `xxx` is the rest of the filename, having an unknown length. This would correspond with regular expression `*`, so instead of `????03??` you might use `????03??*`.

As far as the `find` is concerned: the same regular expression holds here, but as you seem to be working inside a directory (no subdirectories, at first sight), you might consider the `-maxdepth` switch):

```
find . -name "????03??*" | wc -l             // including subdirectories
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "????03??*" | wc -l  // only current directory
```

I would highly advise you to check without `wc -l` first for checking the results. (Oh, I just see the switch `-type f`, that one might still be useful too :-) )

Comment: Works perfect! My filenames are actually much longer, do I have to type f.e. ????03?????????????????????????

Comment: And how can I count these files? (normally find -type f | wc -l)